# At what point does an object lose 50% of escape velocity?

Tags: escape-velocity, karman-line

I find the kalman line an unsatisfactory definition of space. Instead, I will use 50% of escape velocity.

At what distance does this happen? If escape velocity is 11 km s and gravity is 9.81, I am guessing that space starts at a 560 second flight or about 2000 miles.

On the ground pointing up.

Comment: The Kalman line is not defined by any law of nature but rather a definition so we can classify what is in space and what isn't, though this really doesn't have much meaning. 

Your approach to change this for you personally however goes against any common convention, since it would be far beyond any current definition.

To humor your calculation question, we need some more base info. Where does your hypothetical spaceship start it's journey until it deccelerates below 50% escape velocity (On the ground pointing up, on the ground but horizontal, in LEO, any other orbit, ...)? Does it start with

Comment: Four comments: (1) It's Kármán line, not kalman line. While Rudolf E. Kálmán and Theodore von Kármán both made important contributions to space exploration, they were different people. (2) Your guess is off by a lot. It's a bit more than 19000 km altitude. (3) Don't guess; do the math, which is simple. (4) This is a terrible definition of what it means to be in space.

Comment: Aside from the other issues that have been mentioned, why 50% escape velocity? 0.707 times escape velocity at a given altitude corresponds to the circular orbit velocity at that altitude, but 50% of the surface escape velocity doesn't correspond to anything in particular.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a spacecraft drifts outwards, slowing down, it *stays* at escape velocity. The current escape velocity, that is. Escape velocity depends on distance and an object further out needs less velocity to escape. The "11km/s" figure is thus just the escape velocity at the surface, just like "9.81m/s²" is the acceleration due to gravity only at the surface.

But certainly, "escape velocity at 50% of surface escape velocity" makes perfect sense, and we can calculate when that happens.

The escape velocity can be calculated from the mass $M$, Newtonian gravitational constant $G$ and current distance to the centre of a spherically symmetric body $r$

$$v_e = \sqrt{\frac{2GM}{r}}$$

We want half of the surface velocity, so:

$$\sqrt{\frac{2GM}{r_{50\%}}} =  \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{2GM}{r_{\text{surface}}}}$$

Which works out to:

$$r_{50\%} = 4 \cdot r_{\text{surface}}$$

An integer multiple of the planet's radius, for Earth somewhere out in medium Earth orbit. Seems just as arbitrary to me.

A less arbitrary "natural" definition is perhaps $r_{\text{space}} = 1 \cdot r_{\text{surface}}$, space begins where the planet ends. The complicating factor is the atmosphere, and thus a more "natural" definition should depend on some property of the atmosphere. The Kármán line calls it a day by picking some nice round number of kilometres where the atmospheric pressure is getting very low.

Comment: You're missing a factor of two: $$v_e = \sqrt{\frac{2GM}{r}}$$ You'll still get the same result: $$r_{50\%} = 4 \, r_{\text{surface}}$$

Comment: Note that MathJax (like TeX) deals with words in math mode as if the letters in a word represents  individual variables that are multiplied together. For example \$surface\$ becomes $surface$. When you intend to use a word as a word in math mode, use \$\text{surface}\$: $\text{surface}$. Also note that MathJax (like TeX) does funky stuff with the letter "f"". This is intentional. Donald Knuth, the inventor of TeX, spent a lot of time on the letter "f".